# Styling deep InnerHTML

Tags: angular

Sorry im newbie in angular i have a question to styling innerhtml in tree view, here is my code

```
<ul class="tree-view" style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li class="system-main"
        *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div class="system-main__apps">
            <span class="system-main__icon" (click)="expandNode(item)">
                <img src="assets/img/ic_plus.png" class="imageExpand" >
            </span>
            <span style="font-size:1em" class="system-main__name" (click)="clickNode(item)">
               <span class="iconSurat" [innerHTML]="item.icon"></span>{{ item.text }}<br/><span>{{item.hal}}</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul *ngIf="item.expanded">
            <mlpt-arsiplist [items]="item.childNodes" ></mlpt-arsiplist>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

inside `[innerHTML]="item.icon"` is `"<img src='assets/img/urgent icon-01.png' class='iconKcptn'/>"`
how to styling the img innerHTML?

thanks before

Comment: Your CSS should probably target the class name used on the `img` tag - `.iconKcptn`

Comment: already add that in my CSS component but it still doesnt work

Comment: You should include the generated HTML and CSS that's not working. There may be something else going on that you've missed.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, i put the target css globally, maybe caused the component is too deep

thanks before